# How merge elements in List of Arrays in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, list

I have one list of arrays, in which some elemets are the same but one column is not same and it is “created-time" , now I want one of them that has greater "created-time"

my list:

```
List(
  ("hello", " marry", "01/31/2015 17:58:18"),
  ("hello", " marry", "01/31/2015 18:58:18"),
  ("Thanks", "jay", "02/02/2015 20:27:28")
)
```

expected result:

```
List(
  ("hello", " marry", "01/31/2015 18:58:18"),
  ("Thanks", "jay", "02/02/2015 20:27:28")
)
```

Please anyone give the suggestion to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: is it always the 3rd element that is the created-time?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the *specific* code you are having trouble with? Where are the arrays that you talk about in the title? There are no arrays in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You say you have a "list of arrays" but your data example is a list of tuples. This solution assumes that the data is in tuples.

```
val ts = List(("hello", " marry", "01/31/2015 17:58:18")
            , ("hello", " marry", "01/31/2015 18:58:18")
            , ("Thanks", "jay", "02/02/2015 20:27:28"))

ts.groupBy(x => (x._1,x._2)).mapValues(_.maxBy(_._3)).values.toList
```

This also assumes that the order of the result is unimportant, just as long as the correct elements have been selected.

Also worth noting: Because these date strings have the year in the *wrong* place, a simple string comparison will fail to recognize that `"12/31/2015"` comes **before** `"01/01/2016"`.